# Generate UTM parameters from a url parameter for Google Analytics (WP Hosting)

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, regex

I am generating QR Codes and to keep it as clear as possible, I want a short URL, then expand to a full address + UTM or at least have Google Analytics understand.

QR Code payload:

```
https://example.com/as?q=A01
```

The website is on WP, so I can redirect to:

```
https://example.com/A-Subject?q=A01
```

What I am looking for is the next step: Having Google analytics understanding that:

- Source: Business card
- Medium: QR Code
- Campaign: 01

I have tried filters in GA => search and replace `/?q=A01` with `?utm_source=cards&utm_medium=QRCode&utm_campaign=A01`

Problem is that even if the active page is displayed with the correct URL, the UTM parameters are not used/understood by GA (source = (none) for example)

Any idea of what to do?

- Plugin in WP to rewrite URL?
- Javascript in WP to rewrite URL?
- GA ?

[edit]
Doing a bit more research, I suspect the easiest would be to go through .htaccess and do some url rewritting on add_action

In my case, depending on the first letter of the parameter, I would have a few possible outputs:
A = QR Code on a card
=> q=A01 would be rewritten into

utm_source=cards&utm_medium=QRCode&utm_campaign=A01

B = QR Code on a poster
=> q=B07 would be rewritten into

utm_source=poster&utm_medium=QRCode&utm_campaign=B07

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the only complexity is in building the regex, and I'm afraid I'm not great there. Any advice?



Code is letter + 2 digits,
Letter A means cards and letter B or C means poster

/?q=A01 becomes ?utm_source=cards&utm_medium=QRCode&utm_campaign=A01

and

/?q=B07 becomes ?utm_source=poster&utm_medium=QRCode&utm_campaign=B07

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was within the WP Engine, and using conditional redirects by matching args.

my QR Codes were:
`https://example.com/shrt?q=A01`
And I used 301 redirects

Source:
`/shrt?$`

Dest:
`/long-name/?utm_source=cards&utm_medium=QRCode&utm_campaign=A01`

Match Args:
`q=A01`

Pretty sure there would be fancier solutions, but as I create my QRCodes/campaigns one by one, it only takes me 30s to add a new redirect rule when I create a new QRCode...

Problem solved!

Comment: I was using this approach for a long time, but when the site gets more complex, I have to make my own plugin to handle it